# Numpy misindentifying data type

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am calculating the coordinates of a H2O using numpy.
I know that am using proper data types in the creation itself.

```py
r = 0.9820
angle_rad = np.deg2rad((180-103.718)/2)
off_x = r*np.cos(angle_rad)
off_y = r*np.sin(angle_rad)

h2o_base = np.array([['O', np.float64(0.), np.float64(0.), np.float64(0.)], 
            ['H', -off_x, off_y, np.float64(0.)],
            ['H',  off_x, off_y, np.float64(0.)]
           ])
h2o_base
```

I am expecting an array with (string, float, float, foat) data types but when I check it.
the output of this code is

```
array([['O', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0'],
       ['H', '-0.7723363998864039', '0.606482056956765', '0.0'],
       ['H', '0.7723363998864039', '0.606482056956765', '0.0']],
      dtype='<U32')
```

Which is full of string elements.
May I ask for some help with this ?
Shouldn't it automatically detect the proper data type ?

Comment: You are mixing strings and floats without telling numpy the structure of your array first. That being said, maybe Pandas is a better choice here.

Comment: Adding the `dtype` specification, `h2o_base = np.array([['O', np.float64(0.), np.float64(0.), np.float64(0.)],['H', -off_x, off_y, np.float64(0.)],['H',  off_x, off_y, np.float64(0.)]], dtype=object)` should make the trick.

Comment: @NilsWerner thank for the suggestion but I'm gonna need too many of the numpy functions so I didn't want to switch to pandas.

Comment: @amiola Thanks! this worked. If you post this as answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Beware though that object dtype is slower (like lists), and math is hit-or-miss.

Comment: Why are you using arrays for this?  Why not nested list?  And why `np.float65(0.)`?  WHy not just `0.`.  I suspect you don't yet know how to use `numpy` effectively, and are just treating arrays as though they were lists.

Comment: @hpaulj I was initially using list but element-wise calculation were a hassle. npfloat because I was trying to debug a problem with the data type issue and setting it might not be needed but with it there I am sure that the datatype of that particular element is float.  I think "effective" is relative, in my case it is effective (i.e. using it as alist that can easily do array multiplications). Also, thanks for the warning about the speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the [`dtype=object`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types) specification

```
h2o_base = np.array([['O', np.float64(0.), np.float64(0.), np.float64(0.)], 
                     ['H', -off_x, off_y, np.float64(0.)],
                     ['H',  off_x, off_y, np.float64(0.)]], 
                    dtype=object)
```

should make the trick.

Indeed, unlike the built-in `list` type that can hold elements of different types, a `np.array` allows one data type only for all elements.